# Focus on field after keydown event without inserting character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shortcut key <kbd>K</kbd>. It should focus on my input, but I don't want it to insert the letter `K` when it focuses.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) { 
    if (event.which == 75) {
        $('input').focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the standard behaviour of the event. Note however that this will stop the letter `K` from being able to be typed in the `input`. To allow that you need to add a `keydown` handler to the `input` itself which stops the event propagation reaching the `document`. Try this:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 75) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input').focus();
  }
});

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I just updated my answer for you as I realised this method stopped you from typing a `K` in the field itself.

Comment: Kind of a side question. When I focus on my input field and write some data. I need to also listen for enter keydown. When I stopPropagation it does't work ( when enter is pressed nothing happens) . DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/La1bxzx0/1/

Sorry this wasn't in original question as I didn't know I could have a problem like this one.

Comment: In that case you need to add a condition to allow the enter keypress to propagate, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/La1bxzx0/2/

Answer (score 4):

This is another way:

At the time of keydown, if it is `k` and the input does not have focus then prevent the default behavior and give focus to the text field.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 75 && !$('input').is(":focus")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to abruptly stop the propagation, you can also use `return false;`:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 75) {
    $('input').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $('input');

$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
  if(input.is(':focus')){
    return;
  }
  if (e.which == 75) {
        input.focus();
    }
});
```

1. Listen to the `keyup` event;
2. If the input is already focused, don't focus again.